# Disable debugger break in a method scope

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

In a `BackgroundWorker` instance, I handle `Exception` thrown from `DoWork` method into the `RunWorkerCompleted` method by testing `e.Error` property.

```
private string Test()
{
    // For the example, always throw an Exception
    throw new Exception("Unknown error");
}

private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Will always throw an Exception
    e.Result = Test();
}

private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // Exception is managed here
    }
    else
    {
        // Nevers appends in this example
    }
}
```

My problem is the debugger always break the program beacause of a "non-catched" exception (not "non-managed") is thrown by `Test`.

**How to disable the debugger in the `DoWork` scope?**

During debugging, I don't want to break program in the `DoWork` scope, knowing that exception will be managed in `RunWorkerCompleted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the attribute `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` to the event handler it will no longer be picked up by the default settings of the debugger.

```
public class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += Bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += Bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    [DebuggerNonUserCode] //Comment this line to see the difference.
    private static void Bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(); 
    }

    private static void Bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

Note you need to have "Just My Code" enabled in the debugger settings (it is enabled by default).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I tried `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` attribute (with option activated) but debugger always pause the program. Note: my `DoWork` method invokes another method `Request` (from an helper class). I tried to enclose this invocation into a try/catch and re-throw the exception but the debugger pause the program too.

Comment: All layers between it and the DoWork call must have `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` set. If the exception enters then leaves "user code land" before it is handled the error will happen at that point

Comment: Effectively, I needed to add this attribute on the DoWork method and invoked Request method. Thank you very much for this!